# Dynamic Tree to List in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dynamic

I would like to get a list of the elements of my dynamic tree.

I have two types of nodes:

- Indexnodes, which can store two numbers and any amount of children/subtrees (no subtrees are also allowed)
- Datanodes, which can store a number.

[image: An example how it can look like]

```
data MultTree a = DataNode a | IndexNode a a [MultTree a] deriving Show

t1 :: MultTree Int
t1 =  IndexNode 3 42 [IndexNode 3 15 [DataNode 3, DataNode 11, DataNode 12], IndexNode 9 42 [DataNode 42, DataNode 23]]

dataList:: MultTree -> [DataNode] -> [Int]
dataList[] = []
dataList(x:xs) = x : dataList xs
```

The list has to include all datanodes. So for `dataList t1` the list should look like `[3, 11, 12, 42, 23]`.

The function `dataList`, which I have coded does not work.

Does someone have an idea how I can solve it?

Comment: The type signature for `dataList` makes no sense. You should start there. (Also, your implementation is effectively `id :: [a] -> [a]`, which does nothing.)

Comment: Try defining a simpler version first. What would you have to write to get `dataList (DataNode 42)` to return `[42]`?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to let your (modern version of GHC) compiler define it for you. The following sets the appropriate language extension, and sets your desired definition to be the default `toList` definition. I included the assignment, but usually you would just call `toList`.

```
{-# Language DeriveFoldable #-}
module MultTreeList  where

import Data.Foldable(toList)

data MultTree a = DataNode a | IndexNode a a [MultTree a] 
   deriving (Foldable,Show)

t1 :: MultTree Int
t1 =  IndexNode 3 42 [IndexNode 3 15 [DataNode 3, DataNode 11, DataNode 12], IndexNode 9 42 [DataNode 42, DataNode 23]]

dataList :: MultTree a -> [a]
dataList = toList
```

Note the type signature. Your question supposes a signature of `MultTree -> [DataNode] -> [Int]`. This is bad on a few counts. One you forgot the type parameter of MultiTree. Second DataNode is a type constructor, not a type. Including a constructor in a type signature is not allowed. It would be a bit like specifying an `add` function such as

```
add1 :: Int -> 1 -> Int
```

to represent a function which adds one to an Int. I think you intended for a type signature such as I wrote.

Loading the module in GHCI.

```
*MultTreeList> dataList t1
[3,42,3,15,3,11,12,9,42,42,23]
```

Failing the above method, you need a way to map your two constructors to the appropriate list constructions. You have two patterns which need to be addressed,

```
dataList (DataNode a) = ?
dataList (IndexNode a b mts) = ??
```

I'll help get you started.

```
dataList (DataNode a) = [a]
dataList (IndexNode a b mts) = a : b :  (??? mts)
```

Note the type signature of `??? :: [MultTree a] -> [a]`